# How lo load dynamic CSS variables from a file?

Tags: css, vue.js

I want to add to my home dashboard a day/night color mode which will be switched depending on some external conditions.

In the example code below, the "external condition" is a press on the button, which computes new values for CSS variables, which are then used in the `<style>` section:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    switchme: true
  },
  computed: {
    colors() {
      if (this.switchme) {
        return {
          '--fg': 'green',
          '--bg': 'red'
        }
      } else {
        return {
          '--fg': 'blue',
          '--bg': 'yellow'
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#square {
  background-color: var(--bg);
  color: var(--fg);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app" :style="colors">
  <div id="square">{{switchme}}</div>
  <button @click="switchme=!switchme">switchme</button>
</div>
```

In the actual code of the dashboard, there will be much more variables defined and the `colors()` computed variable will be visually large and verbose. It also does not use the capabilities of the IDE when rendering CSS colors.

**My question:** Is there a way to modify such a code to say *"if `switchme` is `true` then load the variables from file `dark.css`, otherwise load the ones from `light.css`"*?
(the content of the files could be preloaded, for instance in `mounted()`)

If so, I believe that the loaded CSS files would be similar to the content below? (with colors depending on the mode)

```
:root {
  --bg: green;
  --fg: red;
}
```