# Is it possible to assign a class to :root?

Tags: javascript, css

As I am thinking about solutions to [another problem of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59301962/how-lo-load-dynamic-css-variables-from-a-file), I am trying to understand to which extend CSS elements can inherit from other elements. Specifically, having the following definition

```
.dark {
  background-color: black;
}
.light {
  background-color: white
}
```

is it possible to programmatically assign (with JS, probably) one of these classes to the `:root` element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done easily with JS.

1. Select the element:

   ```
   const root = document.querySelector(':root')
   ```
2. Assign the class to it:

   ```
   root.classList.add('light')
   ```

All together:

```js
const root = document.querySelector(':root')
root.classList.add('light')
```

Or, instead of having two classes, it might be better to have a `:not()` selector:

```css
:root:not(.dark){
  background-color: white;
}
:root.dark{
  background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: Ah this is perfect, thanks. I just posted an idea similar to yours but targeting the html element. Yours is exactly to the point.

Comment: `document.querySelector(':root')` can be more simply written as `document.documentElement`

Answer (score 0):

I would use (and have used) CSS variables for this.

```
:root {
  --background-color: black;
}

.background {
  background-color: var(--background-color);
}
```

Then change the CSS variable with javascript.

Comment: This is actually what I want to avoid - if you could have a look at the question I linked, I want to put the CSS definitions in a CSS file (or `<style>`) so that I do not have to change them via JS (and keep their definition in JS)

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, `:root` is equivalent to `<html>` ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root)):

> In HTML, :root represents the  element and is identical to the
>   selector html, except that its specificity is higher.

A possible solution would be to apply the class to `<html>`:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].classList.add('dark')
```

```css
.dark {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
hello
</html>
```